# help with creating an action class (java)

Tags: java, class, jsp, struts, action

Hi I have a jsp below:

```
    <form action="testPage.do" method="post" name='testForm' id="testForm">


    <h2><bean:message bundle="test" key="label.header1"/></h2>

    <p><bean:message bundle="test" key="label.dropdown1/> </label>

    <select>
        <option selected="selected">Soccer</option>
        <option>Football</option>
        <option>Baseball</option>
        <option>Hockey</option>
    </select>
    </p>


    <p> 
    <label><bean:message bundle="test" key="label.firstName"/> </label>
    <input type="text"" name="firstname">
    </p>

    <p> 
    <label><bean:message bundle="test" key="label.lastName"/> </label>
    <input type="text"" name="lastname">
    </p>


    </form>
```

I am trying to create an action class that will populate my drop down menu for me and also get the value that is typed into the first and last name textboxes. 
For the action class I have:

```
public class SportAction extends BaseAction {


    public ProcessResult executeFirstTimeInLogic(ActionMapping mapping,
                    ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response,
                    ProcessResult processResult) throws Exception {
            log.info("executeFirstTimeInLogic");
     processResult.setForward(mapping.findForward("next"));
     return processResult;
    }

    public ProcessResult executeSubmitLogic(ActionMapping mapping,
                    ActionForm form,
                    HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response,
                    ProcessResult processResult) throws Exception {
            log.info("executeSubmitLogic");

             return processResult;
     }

}
```

How would I create methods to get the values typed into the textboxes and a method to populate the drop down menu from the action class?

Answer (score 0):

This document help you to implement the population of dropdown..  http://www.vaannila.com/struts/struts-example/struts-html-select-tag-example-1.html.

You can typecast form passed as argument in executeFirstTimeInLogic function to testForm e.g.

Assume the mapping of testform is com.example.TestForm

com.example.TestForm testform = (com.example.TestForm)form;

You have to declare "firstname" and "lastname" as String in com.example.TestForm. And write the getter and setter for both variable.

After typecasting, you can retrieve the value as testform.getFirstname() and test.getLastname()